# selector ^ in jQuery - how to all?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<input id="aaa1" value="vvv">
<input id="aaa2" value="">
<input id="aaa3" value="ooo">
<input id="aaa4" value="">
<input id="aaa5" value="ooo">
<input id="aaa6" value="ooo">

if($('input[id^="aaa"]').val().length == 0){
    $('input[id^="aaa"]').css('background-color', 'red');
}

$("#aaa1").live("click", function(){
  $(this).after("<input id='aaax' value='ooo'>");
});
```

why this working only for first input? if first input value is null then this add css for all input.
how can i make it separately for all input? i use also function live() - i would like added this also for new input

**LIVE EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/Zm5jp/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the `inputs` matched using [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each);

```
$('input[id^="aaa"]').each(function () {
    var self = $(this);

    if (self.val().length == 0) {
        self.css('background-color', 'red');
    }
}
```

As stated in the [docs for `val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val);

> Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements.

I.e. your code translates as "if the first input value is empty, set the background CSS for all elements"

Comment: PS. `self.val()` can be written more efficiently using `this.value`.

Answer (score 2):

[`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) gets the value of the *first element in the matched set*. You'll have to [iterate over the set](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$('input[id^="aaa"]').each(function() {
    if($(this).val().length == 0) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
});
```